# Perl Regex Match and loop HTML Comments

Tags: regex, perl

I have a log file with data in format :

```
<!-- 12/15/16 01:02:27:950.125
 DATA1 -->
<!-- 12/15/16 01:02:27:950.373
 DATA2 -->
<!-- 12/15/16 01:02:27:950.921
 DATA3: Text1 -->
<!-- 12/15/16 01:02:27:951.066
 DATA4: Text2 -->
```

I need to extract and loop all the data inside the comments.
I am reading the file and saving data as one string.
I have tried a few solutions but getiing "undef" on match

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval );
use Date::Format;
use DateTime;    
use warnings;
.
.
.
       if ( open(ORIGFILE, $filepath) ) {

            my @wrp_record_content = <ORIGFILE>;
            # my $content = join('', @wrp_record_content);
            # my @matches = $content =~ s/<!--(.*)-->//g;
            # my $data;

            # while ( <ORIGFILE> ) {
            #     $data .= $_;
            # }

            # while ( $data =~ m/<!--(.*)-->/g ) {
            #     print Dumper('===DATA===');
            #     print Dumper($data);
            # }

            my $content = join('', @wrp_record_content);
            #print Dumper('------CONTENT------');
            #print Dumper($content);
            #print Dumper('------ CONTENT ENDED ------');

            my @matches;
            while ($content =~ /<!--.*?-->/gs) {
            push @matches, $1;
            }

            foreach my $m (@matches) {
                print Dumper('===MATCH===', "\n");
                print Dumper($m);
            }
       }
```

Can someone please guide on where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in `$1`. You must add *capturing parentheses* to your regex pattern

```
$content =~ /<!--(.*?)-->/gs
```

You have done it correctly in the loop that you commented out!

Comment: thankyou sir but the above commented regex displays the entire file content and not in loops. thanks for the direction. i'll work that way

Comment: @zeetit: That's because you print `$data` in the commented code instead of the captured string in `$1`

Comment: Aah.. thanks.. I found where I was going wrong. thanks for guiding. Can accept answer in 5 min. will do so